# GIGABYTE GA-Z170X-Gaming 3 Ram Issue

Tags: memory, motherboard, gigabit-ethernet

I just built a machine and can only get this mobo to boot with one stick of ram from this kit.

Corsair Vengeance LPX 64GB DDR4 DRAM 2666MHz C16 Memory Kit for DDR4 Systems

Comment: Will it post with more than one stick but not boot? If so, are they showing up correctly in the BIOS? Is XMP enabled with the correct profile?

Comment: It will post and boot with one stick only anything else Nada. How do I enable xmp?

Comment: [XMP can be enabled under the Advanced CPU Core Settings in the BIOS.](http://download.gigabyte.us/FileList/Manual/mb_manual_ga-z170x-gaming3_e.pdf) Separately, have you tried resetting CMOS after installing the RAM?

Comment: I have not I'll give that a shot  I just tried running another stick in the other red slot and nothing but if I put the other stick in the socket right next to the first it boots so now it booting with 32gb but when I stick  the last two in it won't boot or post

Comment: What processor?

Comment: Strange, the kit should work with dual channel systems.

Comment: Intel 7th Gen Intel Core Desktop Processor i7-7700K (BX80677I77700K)

Comment: I was able to enable XMP mode and the two sticks are not running at the correct speed of my ram. Havent tried to install the last two sticks yet.

Comment: It wont wont boot with the two extra stick with XMP mode :(

Answer (score 0):

Found out the ram I have only works on two slots on this board

Comment: Thanks for closing the loop on your question.  Can you elaborate a little?

Answer (score -1):

I realize this is a question from 2017 but I thought I'd share my experience.

Manually configure the RAM to operate at a slower speed.

I purchased a Kingston HyperX Black 32GB 4X8 Kit 2666MHZ DDR4 but my computer wouldn't boot when all (4) sticks were installed until I forced the kit to operate slightly slower.